# wild card in command module in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a directory /tmp/abc. In /tmp/abc i have 5 files few are text files one property file and one jar file. I want to run that jar file.

But the issue is that the jar name is dynamic based on build. Is there any way that i can run the jar without hard coding and without passing it as extra variable(because i wont be knowing the name)?

Right now what i am trying to do is to list the content of file and then try to save that in a var and then trying to use wild card to run the jar. But it is not working

Here is my ansible code:

```
- name: read content of directory
  command: "ls /tmp/abc"
  register: file_content

- name: run the jar
  command: "java -jar /tmp/abc/*.jar"
```

Is there any better way of doing it?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Find module will be better to resolve this as it's from Ansible and works perfactly against all operating, still if you stuck somewhere where no Ansible module is there and use shell module instead of command as shell uses /bin/bash, there most feature like pipelining will work easily but not with command nodule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any better way of doing it?

Yes. Use the [`find` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html) to search for the exact file name of your jar and run it from its absolute path.

Find returns a list of matches in the `files` list. If you know and trust your file structure, you just have to keep the first and only result and get its `path` attribute.

Here is an example.

My test directory created from your description

```
/tmp/abc/
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
├── c.properties
├── d.jar
└── e.txt
```

My playbook

```yaml
---
- name: Run dynamically named jar
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: find jar files in /tmp/abc
      find:
        paths:
          - /tmp/abc
        patterns:
          - "*.jar"
        file_type: file
        recurse: no
      register: jarsearch

    - name: Show the command we would run
      debug:
        msg: "java -jar {{ (jarsearch.files | first).path }}"
```

And the result

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [Run dynamically named jar] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [find jar files in /tmp/abc] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show the command we would run] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "java -jar /tmp/abc/d.jar"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Many thanks. It worked. I would really appreciate if you can tell me what pipe(|) does in ansible? Like in this line Javasearch.files | first. Any information or link will help me to understand. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It's the jinja2 operator to apply a filter: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#other-operators